# unity | В чем заключается ошибка?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ошибка при попытка отключить объект
[image]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 4):

Русским по серому написано, что в инспекторе не воткнут нужный объект в нужно поле.